# Why doesn't prometheus.exe execute?

Tags: weblogic12c, prometheus

I am currently working on scraping metrics from WebLogic server using [weblogic monitoring exporter](https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-monitoring-exporter) . I am trying to display these metrics using prometheus. My prometheus.yml file contents are:-

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'wls-exporter'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.
    metrics_path: '/wls-exporter/metrics'

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:7001']
      basic_auth:
        username: 'weblogic'
        password: 'password1'
```

Now , whenever I execute prometheus.exe, nothing happens. 
So what am I doing wrong in here?
PS:- I am on Windows 7

Comment: What does Prometheus log?

Comment: @brian-brazil Hi, It is giving this error:- "Error loading config couldn't load configuration (--config.file=prometheus.yml): parsing YAML file prometheus.yml: \"localhost:7001/wls-exporter\" is not a valid hostname""

Comment: Ok now it is giving this weird error:-"compaction failed" and some Access is denied to some Data\\01C........ folder

Comment: It sounds like something has gotten very messed up with your configs. I'd suggest starting from a clean slate.

Comment: I had similar issue. Clearing the data folder and then executing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last log I suggest try  running prometheus with '`storage.tsdb.no-lockfile=true'`
I had several cases on win7 that data folder got corrupted and prometheus not starting. When I used the above flag I had no issues running prometheus on win7 or win10